# ClamTK menu not working

Tags: 16.04

ClamAv
ClamTK
Ubuntu16.04 LTS

Start ClamTK from Unity it starts but  the menus  don’t work.
Start ClamTK from Terminal the output follows.
luis@luis-Ubuntu-16:~$ ClamTK
ClamTK: command not found
luis@luis-Ubuntu-16:~$

Synaptic shows it is installed.

How to fix this 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ClamTk has executable named `clamtk` (located in `/usr/bin/clamtk`).

You should enter `clamtk` in terminal to start ClamTk.

Comment: The Terminal command is with lower case. ClamTk opens but icons don't work the some as opening from Unity. This is the problem now